# og:description not displaying on LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to troubleshoot an issue regarding the description of our links not displaying on the LinkedIn site, and I've noticed that the og:description tag is not being used. This is also the same for other sites that share their content with LinkedIn .

Does LinkedIn no longer display the description of a site?

Thanks.